# Probelem with Pandas dataframe merge

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I tried to us the pandas merge function but I got an keyerror message. The keys have the same type and the same name, what could be the problem:
My code is here:

```
print(data_EURUSD.head())
print(data_XAUUSD.head())
print(data_EURUSD.index)
print(data_XAUUSD.index)

data=pd.merge(data_EURUSD, data_XAUUSD, on='date', how='left')

print(data)
```

The result:

```
                 askclose

date                         
2017-05-19 21:00:00   1.12090
2017-05-21 21:00:00   1.11999
2017-05-22 21:00:00   1.12402
2017-05-23 21:00:00   1.11840
2017-05-24 21:00:00   1.12195

                 askclose
date                         
2017-01-20 22:00:00   1209.47
2017-01-23 22:00:00   1218.46
2017-01-24 22:00:00   1209.41
2017-01-25 22:00:00   1201.18
2017-01-26 22:00:00   1189.04

 DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-19 21:00:00', '2017-05-21 21:00:00',

           '2018-12-26 22:00:00', '2018-12-27 22:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=500, freq=None)

 DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-20 22:00:00', '2017-01-23 22:00:00',

           '2018-12-26 22:00:00', '2018-12-27 22:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=500, freq=None)

....

KeyError: 'date'
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because you have a datetime `index`, 'date' is not a `column` it is a `index` value.

You should do:

```
pd.merge(data_EURUSD, data_XAUUSD, how='left',right_index=True,left_index=True)
```

In these situations I prefer to use `pd.df.join()` which already seeks to join based on shared indices. The code would be:

```
data = data_EURUSD.join(data_XAUUSD,how='left')
```